# Rails fat model example, is this the right way of thinking?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, controller, business-logic

If I have two tables in a DB  User and Userinfo (split for **normalisation** purposes) I generate the two models User,  UserInfo and use them as normal via relationships.

Later on I have section of my application that reads and writes to both, however, there is a fair amount of business logic on creating entries for example looking up other tables for conditional rules, string building etc.

Would it make sense to make a third model (a non-database-backed model)  to handle all this and to create/save via the other two models? or should I keep this in the controller?

Another example could be importing a CSV file where all the data is split between different tables, separate models as used by the rest of the application. Could  I use a model defining each row that handles saving the imported data via the other models. Or again should this be in the controller?

I am interested in the best practices when developing large rails applications.

Comment: should read normalizing  not de-normalizing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're normalizing (minimizing redundancy) rather than de-normalizing.

I don't know your application, so please take this as something to consider rather than a recommended best practice: what I typically like do in a situation like this is hide the Userinfo behind the User, so that the User is the only part of the application that even knows there is a Userinfo. This keeps things simple and consistent and DRY across the other clients of the code (controllers, other models, and *you* when you interact with it in the console).

Introducing a third model might serve the same purpose, but it's also adding conceptual weight to the application.

Comment: So what your saying is have the two models but move the logic to main one (User) and only refer to that from the controller?  like this example in the main answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066847/two-tables-serving-as-one-model-in-rails

Comment: PS reading your book  The RSpec Book: Behaviour-Driven Development with RSpec, Cucumber, and Friends very useful

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on why you split the user data into two tables in the first place - what problem was it supposed to solve. Figure that out and try to apply the same logic to the models.

In any case, I agree that it makes sense to create a third model that encapsulates the complexity of working with the other two. This lets you present a simpler interface to other layers of the application (controllers, views). However, you'll have to watch carefully how far you're going with this. If you find yourself re-implementing most of ActiveRecord::Base by delegating calls to your encapsulated components, then it may be time to reconsider.

BTW, what you did isn't de-normalization. De-normalization in the context of a relational database means creating redundancy (check out the [Wikipedia article on normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), de-normalization is the opposite). This is usually done in order to improve performance by reducing the amount of joins required.